# Should I be worried about the load balancing choices of the Cassandra C++ driver?

Tags: c++, networking, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a tiny Cassandra cluster of 4 nodes running Cassandra 3.9.

I pass the 4 IP addresses to the `connect()` function and when I check connections with `netstat -a4n | grep 9042`, I can see that they are all connected. Note that whether I pass 1 IP or 4 to the `connect()`, the result is the same once fully connected, including the double connection to the 10.0.1.1 node... (10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.3 are seeds, but somehow only 10.0.1.1 has a double connection, so I'm not too sure why that happens with that one, I tried to shuffle the list of IPs used to connect, and again, it made no difference in the end.)

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:45012      10.0.1.3:9042      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:48400      10.0.1.4:9042      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:51514      10.0.1.2:9042      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:56460      10.0.1.1:9042      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:56452      10.0.1.1:9042      ESTABLISHED
```

When I look at the output of `nodetool status`, it looks pretty good:

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address   Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack
UN  10.0.1.1  7.92 MiB   256          76.1%             (id)     rack1
UN  10.0.1.4  12.26 MiB  256          77.7%             (id)     rack1
UN  10.0.1.3  10.08 MiB  256          72.2%             (id)     rack1
UN  10.0.1.2  8.77 MiB   256          74.0%             (id)     rack1
```

(Note: I removed the ID, they are not useful here).

However, network wise, I see a huge disparity when I look at the amount of data transferred to those machines. I use the `iptables -L -nvx` command, and to my surprise I see that I send about 3 times more packets and nearly 20 times more data to the first Cassandra node:

```
6856 13581751 RETURN     all  --  eth1   *  10.0.1.1    0.0.0.0/0
2736   816810 RETURN     all  --  eth1   *  10.0.1.2    0.0.0.0/0
2831   807426 RETURN     all  --  eth1   *  10.0.1.3    0.0.0.0/0
2745   806023 RETURN     all  --  eth1   *  10.0.1.4    0.0.0.0/0
```

(6,856 / 2,736 = 2.51  and  13,581,751 / 806,023 = 16.85)

I suppose that in a way it does not matter much as long as the nodes are not busy anyway, but I'm still wondering why would I be seeing such a huge disparity? Why wouldn't all 4 connections participate at a similar level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drivers will use the contact points as an initial connection point to setup the connection pool. After this the pool is created based on your schema topology, local balancing policy and pooling options. For reference some useful docs here (sorry if you already seen these):

http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/

http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/configuration/

The additional traffic may very well be the control connection the driver uses which keeps itself up to date with the schema topology to aid the way the driver functions:

http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/basics/schema_metadata/

Comment: That last link is interesting. We use a proxy so we connect just once, but I've noticed that the first connection can be *really slow*.